# rxjs: recursive Observable emission inside map

Tags: javascript, observable, rxjs6

I am pulling my hair out a little with attempting to group data recursively in rxjs. There seems to be alot of good examples around with different use cases but I cant seem to refactor the code around to fit my requirements.

The central problem that I can infer is that in my map operator I have a conditional return which is either a non-observable or an observable. Is there a way I can refactor to account for this discrepency?

Ideally this function would group an original "flat" array by an arbitrary amount of columns that are passed in as the cols argument.

Each time the criteria is satisfied it would 
append to an array in the format 
{ key: col_name, elements : [...col_elements] } where elements would be another array of elements in the same format, or a straight list of elements.

The below function works when only grouping the columns once ( and thus never requiring the observable within map to emit ).

```
//group data n times based on passed string[] of column attributes
  group_data(elements: Observable<any>, cols: string[], index=0) : Observable<any> {
    let col = cols[index]

    return elements.pipe(
      //groupby column value
      RxOp.groupBy((el:any) => this.get_groupingValue(el, col)),

      //place key inside array
      RxOp.mergeMap((group) => group.pipe(
        RxOp.reduce((acc, cur) => [...acc, cur], ["" + group.key]))
      ),
      // map to key:group
      RxOp.map((arr:any) =>

          cols.length <= index + 1?
          // no more grouping req
          { 'key': arr[0], 'elements': arr.slice(1) } :

          //group recursively, returns Observable instead of array:(
          { 'key': arr[0], 'elements':
            this.group_data(from(arr.slice(1)), cols, index + 1)
              .pipe(
                RxOp.tap(t=> console.log(t)), // not logged
                RxOp.reduce((acc, val) => [...acc, val], [])

              )
          }),
      RxOp.toArray()
    )
  }

//simplified data example:

data = [{id: 'idA', type: 'project', parents: null },
 {id: 'idB', type: 'project', parents: null },
 {id: 'idC', type: 'episode', parents: ['idA'] },
 {id: 'idD', type: 'episode', parents: ['idB'] },
 {id: 'idE', type: 'scene', parents: ['idA', 'idC'] },
 {id: 'idF', type: 'scene', parents: ['idB', 'idD'] }] 

// 1 column passed works correctly as below

group_data(elements: from(data), ['project'])

/* outputted data:
[{key: 'idA', 
  elements: [ {id: 'idC', type: 'episode', parents: ['idA'] },
              {id: 'idE', type: 'scene', parents: ['idA', 'idC'] }]},
{key: 'idB', 
  elements: [ {id: 'idD', type: 'episode', parents: ['idA'] },
              {id: 'idF', type: 'scene', parents: ['idA', 'idC'] }]},

{key: null,
  elements: [ {id: 'idA', type: 'project', parents: [] }
              {id: 'idB', type: 'project', parents: [] }]}
]
*/

// 2 columns not working correctly
group_data(elements: from(data), ['project', 'episode'])
/*[{key: 'idA', 
  elements: Observable},
{key: 'idB', 
  elements: Observable},
{key: null, 
  elements: Observable}
]*/
```

Comment: its still hard to understand what you're trying to achieve. maybe some examples of input & output data would help. probably, it'd be also helpful to understand what is the purpose of this grouping

Comment: updated to include output/input example

Comment: Four letters: KISS !!

Answer (score 0):

The approach i needed to take was to restructure so that I could use mergeMap instead of map - which meant i needed two observables at the condition instead of one. From there i just needed to refactor so that the mapping to key, elements was done after the mergeMap.

This is still my first foray into rxjs, so my explanation isn't great and my summary of the problem also wasnt great. Importantly, at least its behaving as expected now.

```
//group data n times based on passed string[] of column attributes
  group_data(elements: Observable<any>, cols: string[], index=0) : Observable<any> {
    let col = cols[index]

    let grouping = elements.pipe(
      //groupby column value
      RxOp.groupBy((el:any) => this.get_groupingValue(el, col)),

      //place key inside array
      RxOp.mergeMap((group) => group.pipe(
        RxOp.reduce((acc, cur) => [...acc, cur], ["" + group.key]))
      )
    )


    return grouping.pipe(
      RxOp.mergeMap((arr) =>
        (
        cols.length <= (index +1) ?

        //no more grouping required
        of(arr.slice(1)) : 

        //group again
        this.group_data(from(arr.slice(1)), cols, index + 1))

        // reduce result and put the key back in
        .pipe(
          RxOp.reduce((acc, cur) => [...acc, cur], ["" + arr[0]])
        )
      ),

      // map to key:group
      RxOp.map(arr => ({
          key: arr[0],
          elements: arr.slice(1)
        })
      ),
      RxOp.toArray()
    )
```